# Gráfico de dependencia parcial, familia multinomial

Tags: r, machine-learning, model, visualización-de-datos, estadística

Estoy usando el paquete gbm para ajustar un modelo *gradient boosting* de familia multinomial.

Al hacer los gráficos de dependencia parcial salen muy confusos (primera imagen) y quisiera mostrarlos como en la segunda imagen, donde cada línea es una categoría de la variable dependiente.

El código usando los datos iris es el siguiente:

```
library(gbm)
data(iris)
GBM.model = gbm(Species ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data = 
iris,distribution = "multinomial")
plot.gbm(GBM.model, "Petal.Length")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguno sabe como hacer para visualizarlo como en la segunda imagen?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Una manera de lograrlo seria extrayendo los datos del gráfico. Para ello basta con pasar el parámetro `return.grid=TRUE`, a la función `plot.gbm`

```
library(gbm)
data(iris)
str(iris)
GBM.model = gbm(Species ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data = 
iris,distribution = "multinomial")
#Guardamos los datos en X
X<-plot.gbm(GBM.model,"Petal.Length",return.grid=TRUE)
```

Una vez que tenemos los datos guardados en `X`, podemos transformarlos para  gratificarlos por ejemplo en `ggplot2` o en alguna otra librería de gráficos.  En este caso el paquete `gbm` usa `lattice` para sus gráficas y podríamos hacer una gráfica igual a la de tu ejemplo con el siguiente código

```
#Pasamos los datos a formato lagro    
df<-NULL
for(i in colnames(X$y)){
#Atencion
#X es un data.frame cuya columna "y" es una matriz
#Para pasarla a formato ancho
#Cada una de las columnas de la matriz "y" se pasan a la columna y del nuevo df
#En la columna Petal.Length de df siempre se pasa la misma columna de X 
#Y en la columna Species (Por la que se agrupa para dar color)
#se pasa el nombre de la columna de la matriz "y"

    aux<-data.frame(y=X$y[,i],Petal.Length=X$Petal.Length,Species=i)
    df<-rbind(df,aux)
}
#Mostramos un resumen de los datos
str(df)
#Gráfica usando el paquete lattice
lattice::xyplot(y ~ Petal.Length,
     data = df,
     type = "l",
     groups=Species,
     ylab="f(Petal.Length)")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]